# Reference groovy variables over multiple script parts in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In a Jenkins job, I have a groovy script, that is split in two parts. It does something before SCM and does some other thing at the end of the job as last build instruction.

Now, I need to access a variable in the second part, that I set in the first part.

How to do that?

I tried to mark a variable as a field with `@Field Boolean myFlag = false`, but still myFlag cannot be accessed in the second part of the script.

Interpreter says:
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myFlag for class: Script1`

Does anyone know how to accomplish accessing a variable from the first part of the script in the second?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried defining your variables globally ?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass these variables as the Jenkins Job's parameters. That way you have access to the variables throughout.

It was not clear from your question if you're running a single script in the job or if you're executing multiple scripts.

Comment: Actually I do not know if the scripts are considered one script or if they are interpreted separately (just starting with jenkins+groovy). I think it is two separate scripts. When I do a `println bindings.variables`, the job parameters are available in the pre-SCM script, but they do not show up in the build-part, whereas `build.buildVariableResolver` is defined in the build part, but is not available in the pre SCM script :-/ How to deal with job parameters in both scripts?